WCF doesn't prompt for credentials -Localhost
I came across this weird scenario after upgrading to windows 11.
WCF application was working and prompts in browser for authentication in windows 10. After enterprise OS upgrade WCF is taking anonymous authentication(and does not prompts for credentials) when running on the localhost Visual studio 2022. The UI Client is getting 401 unauthorized error when accessing endpoints. WCF config and code has not changed during this upgrade.
Please find my WCF setting.
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
    <service name="XYZ_WCFRestService.RestServiceTLJira" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WinAuth" contract="XYZ_WCFRestService.IRestServiceTLJira" name="WinAuth" behaviorConfiguration="web"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
            <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="http://localhost:6321/RestServiceTLJira.svc"/>
            </baseAddresses>
        </host>
    </service>
</services>
<bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WinAuth" openTimeout="00:40:00" closeTimeout="00:40:00" receiveTimeout="00:40:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
            <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
            </security>
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
            <webHttp helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="https"/>
</protocolMapping>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
<diagnostics>
    <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" maxMessagesToLog="3000"/>
</diagnostics>

</system.serviceModel>
This is legacy application , I am not much aware about WCF windows authentication.
Any help? How to fix this?

Experiencing WCF application anonymous authentication issues after upgrading to Windows 11 may be caused by your system's authentication settings or IIS configuration. On Windows 11, make sure that your application (or IIS app pool) has Windows authentication enabled and not anonymous authentication.
